# git:status icons not showing for web application

Tags: asp.net, git, visual-studio-2010, git-extensions

i have git 1.8.3.

- Created a web Application in Visual Studio 2010;
- open it; right-click on solutions file
- select "Git Create repository";

git Showing Status icon only for .sln file.

for windows application it works fine.Show All Files with + sign (New file)

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi. We moved to Visual Studio 2012, We didn't faced any problem for Visual Studio 2012